# Deleting feature classes with similar name in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, delete, similarity

I have a script that does a dissolve on polygons with a common field. I'm only interested in keeping the outputs that contain more than one polygon. I'm new to python and having trouble writing a script that will delete all the polygons that have a name starting with 'dissolve_*'. I get an error saying "name 'fnmatch' is not defined. Below is the script. The problem is at the very end of it.

***Found the Solution***  I had to move the Delete_management outside of the SearchCursor. I've updated the scritp to one that works and deleted extra bits as per PolyGeos request.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2 Desktop

```
import arcpy, os, sys
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
PD_ED = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
NullwhereClause = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
output_dir = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

# Local variables for dissolve:
PD_ED_fld = ['Add_PNTID', 'PD_NO', 'ED_NO']
PD_PNTID_Lay = 'PD_PNTID_Lay'
dissolveField = ['Add_PNTID']
dissolve_lay ="lay_dis"
try:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(PD_ED, PD_ED_fld, TestPDwhereClause) as PDcursor:
        for PDrow in PDcursor:
            # Returns string values for the field names specified
            PDPNTIDrow = str(PDrow[0])

            # where statement to select a single PNTID value from the field 
            PDwhereClause = 'Add_PNTID =' +PDPNTIDrow

            # Process: Make Feature Layer
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(PD_ED, PD_PNTID_Lay, PDwhereClause)

            dissolve = arcpy.Dissolve_management(PD_PNTID_Lay, disPDoutput, dissolveField, "", "SINGLE_PART", "")

            # Process: Make Feature Layer
            dissolveMakLay = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(dissolve, dissolve_lay)
            # Process: Get Count - if the count in the layer is greater than 1 an output is created otherwise "Only one polygon found" is printed
            dissolveCount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(dissolveMakLay).getOutput(0))
            if dissolveCount > 1:
                arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(dissolveMakLay, output_dir, disPDoutManyPoly)
                print("More than one Polygon found")
            else:
                print("Only one polygon found")

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
    arcpy.AddError(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
except Exception as e:
    print e.args[0]
    arcpy.AddError(e.args[0])

try:
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("dissolve_*"):
        arcpy.Delete_management(fc)

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print arcpy.GetMessages(2)
    arcpy.AddError(arcpy.GetMessages(2))
except Exception as e:
    print e.args[0]
    arcpy.AddError(e.args[0])
```

Comment: 1. `import fnmatch`. 2. Where is the `fcs` constructed, what does it contain?

Comment: You have not presented us with a code snippet that works up to where you are stuck.  Instead of just copying out a function, I think you should, while testing, remove your `def` statement and set test values for each of the variables that would be coming in via parameters in your actual code.  You should then test that code snippet to make sure that it works up to where you are stuck, before posting.

Comment: Yes, I did test the script. Everything works up until the fnmatch section.

Comment: @Alex Tereshenkov, the fc refers to the feature classes that were created using the dissolve function. They are in th ServiceArea_Outliers feature dataset. I'll try importing fnmatch and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Without wanting to be pedantic when I run your script as-is I get `NameError: name 'arcpy' is not defined`.  When I add an `import arcpy` at the start and re-run I get `NameError: name 'PD_ED' is not defined`.  We should not have to guess values for *your* variables to get our testing to where *you* are seeing an error.  Please try to present `the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself` rather than just copying a function and calling it a snippet.